# How to show combobox in ExtJS grid panel using extjs 6.0.1

Tags: extjs

How to show combobox in Extjs grid panel using extjs 6.0.1

I saw widget column example but it is rendering combobox only when user clicks on a cell. How to show combobox by default?

Can someone provide a sample in fiddle?

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`widgetcolumn`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Widget):

> A widget column is configured with a widget config object which
>   specifies an xtype to indicate which type of Widget or Component
>   belongs in the cells of this column.

Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/16bt